# Printing Commandline Arguments x86 Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

First off I'm new to assembly but have a decent background in c++. My problem stems from a tutorial I was following on **Commandline arguments using assembly**.

When the program is run it does everything it is suppose to do according to the tutorial, which is display the list of program inputs:
`./asm1 arg1 arg2 arg3`

The concern is when you provide an astrisk as the argument:
`./asm1 *`

> It effectively does a **/usr/bin/ls** on the CWD.

**My question is how do I prevent this, and any advice on a better way to implement this program.**

> Replaced:

```
; the loop
        cmp ecx, eax        ; if ecx not equal to eax
        jne begin_for_loop  ; jmp to loop, else exit
```

> With:

```
; the loop
         cmp ecx, eax        ; if ecx not equal to eax
         jmp begin_for_loop  ; jmp to loop, else exit
```

> ***And I found a bigger issue where the program prints ENV variables to the screen.***

#### Here's the original program below:

```
; FOR LOOP: Print commandline arguments> an equivalent program to 
this in assembly
SECTION .data

    argv db "Arguments = %s",10,0
    argc db "Argument Count = %d",10,0

SECTION .text
; allow access to printf
extern printf
; make main_function available externally
global main


main:    ; int main (int argc, char* argv[])
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    sub esp, 10

    mov eax, DWORD [ebp + 8]    ; points to argc
    mov ebx, DWORD [ebp + 12]   ; points to argv
    mov ecx, 0      ; mov ZERO to count register

begin_for_loop:
    ; always preserve values prior to external function calls
    ; external function calls may modify values you placed in registers
    push ebx    ; preserve ebx; holds argument address
    push eax    ; preserve eax; holds number of arguments
    push ecx    ; preserve ecx; holds the counter

    ; call printf
    push DWORD [ebx]
    push argv
    call printf
    add esp, 8  ; clean up the stack

    ; always restore in backwards order
    pop ecx     ; restore counter
    pop eax     ; restore number of arguments
    pop ebx     ; restore argument address

    inc ecx     ; increase our counter by 1
    add ebx, 4  ; move to next argument in the array

    ; the loop
    cmp ecx, eax        ; if ecx not equal to eax
    jne begin_for_loop  ; jmp to loop, else exit


    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Expected Output:

```
$ ./asm5 me you them us
Arguments = ./asm5
Arguments = me
Arguments = you
Arguments = them
Arguments = us
```

Questionable Output:

```
$ ./asm5 me you them us *
Arguments = ./asm5
Arguments = me
Arguments = you
Arguments = them
Arguments = us
Arguments = asm1
Arguments = asm1.asm
Arguments = asm1.o
Arguments = asm2
Arguments = asm2.asm
Arguments = asm3
Arguments = asm3.asm
Arguments = asm4
Arguments = asm4.asm
Arguments = asm5
Arguments = asm5.asm
Arguments = asm-template.asm
Arguments = compile-asm.sh
Arguments = cpp_libs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On POSIX systems if you start a program from a shell *the shell* will perform so-called globbing, expanding the `*` and replacing it with the matching files; the result will then be used as the arguments for the invocation of your program.

You cannot do anything to prevent it from your program, the arguments you see are indeed those it got from the shell (IOW, they are the arguments that have been passed to `exec`).

If you want to pass a literal `*` to your program when starting it from a shell, you'll have to quote it.

```
./asm5 me you them us "*"
```

Of course none of this will happen if some other program launches your program passing the arguments straight to `exec`, without the shell getting in the way.

---

> > Replaced:
>
> ```
> ; the loop
>          cmp ecx, eax        ; if ecx not equal to eax
>          jne begin_for_loop  ; jmp to loop, else exit
> ```
>
> > With:
>
> ```
> ; the loop
>          cmp ecx, eax        ; if ecx not equal to eax
>          jmp begin_for_loop  ; jmp to loop, else exit
> ```
>
> > ***And I found a bigger issue where the program prints ENV variables to the screen.***

This comes from the fact that you are ignoring the NULL that terminates the `argv` arguments list, and you are going on reading what's next; this in your case happens to be the environment memory block.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. For better clarification i'm also new to linux. But i think you mean that ```*``` gets expanded to whatever ENV the SHELL is in for the user. and what exactly is ```exec```. Sorry for the noob comment but i'm coming from windows.

Comment: @Sebastian No! This is not about environment variables, it's about files.  The asterisk stands for “an arbitrarily named file” and since there are no slashes in the file name, the shell is going to expand this to all files in the current working directory (type `pwd` to find out what that is).  You can do things like `/usr/bin/*sh` to find all files in `/usr/bin` whose name ends in `sh`.  All of this is expanded by the shell.  It's not like on Windows where you have to do this expansion yourself.

Comment: @Sebastian: as fuz explained, the environment is completely unrelated; the shell expands the content of the current directory _as arguments_. The fact that you are seeing the environment variables when you change the conditional jump comes from the fact that you are mistakenly reading the memory that happens to come next, which is the environment block.

Comment: Also, `exec` is the system call used to execute a process; it receives the arguments used to start your program as parameters.

Comment: @Sebastian: The actual system call (used by the shell in this case) is [`execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[],
char *const envp[]);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).  People sometimes say `exec` as shorthand for that.  But notice that it gets an array of `char*` for each arg separately.  Related: [Why is C/C++ main argv declared as "char\* argv\[\]" rather than just "char\* argv"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/385830) for more background on how the OS passes args to newly-execed processes.

Comment: @Sebastian: "newly execed process" can be a confusing description (but it's hard to say it any other way in English), because `execve` doesn't create a *new* process ID, it *replaces* an existing process (usually created with `fork`) with a fresh process created by the program-loader.  That's why in the shell, if you run `exec bash`, it *replaces* your current shell with a newly-run bash.  e.g. if you make a shell script and put `exec /bin/ls` near the top, nothing later will run because the shell replaced itself with `ls`, which then exits.

Comment: Windows has a system call that combines fork+exec, creating a new process running the specified executable.  But they're separate in POSIX, and there is no combined system call that does both.  (copy-on-write memory mapping makes `fork` fairly cheap to implement; `fork()` returns twice, once in the parent and once in the child.)